# How to use java jar file in scala language IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

**Step1:** I was create java jar file in eclipse.

**step2:** Then i add a jar in scala using addExternalJar in scala IDE.

**step3:** In example.scala file i was call a respected method in jar, like

Test td = new test();

td.return(value);

But its not run , error throws throws like not found test(). Please help me to find right solution thank you...

Comment: we need 1) code sample with import statements, 2) copy of error messages - is it compile time or runtime, 3) your classpath

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov 1. Its compile time error. not found: type EyeTracker
[error]       val track = new EyeTracker()

Comment: 2. My code look like this:  class MyThread1(var getvalue: String) extends Callable[String] {

    override def call(): String = {
     
      
      val track = new EyeTracker()
      track.eyelike(getvalue)
     
     
      try {
        Thread.sleep(2)
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => 
      }
      val getTrack = track.getEye_position
      
    }
  }

Comment: You need to check that your jar is on the classpath and that you have corresponding import statements

Comment: iam new to scala, i dont know how to check classpath and all

Comment: it's a Java thing. You can find it in your IDE. import statements are similar to Java as well

Answer (score 1):

I got it, just do $./activator eclipse update in terminal jar file is loaded.